# Configure SMTP using spring-boot-admin

Tags: java, smtp, spring-boot-admin

I like to send notification emails with spring-boot-admin-server. I have configured it as described here:

http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.3.0/#mail-notifications

However, I do not know how the SMTP is to be used. I think all of them (gmail, gmx,...) require some sort of authentication, isn't it? How can I provide the authentication? 
Or is the idea that you set up your own SMTP server without any authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using the `spring-boot-starter-mail` you can configure the mail sender using the `spring.mail.*`-properties. Username can be set via `spring.mail.username` and password via `spring.mail.password`.

Have a look at the corresponding [appendix in spring-boot`s reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

p.s.: The SBA 1.3.0 is totally outdated - you should update!